# Agregar un poligono a un analisis de PCA en R

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un Analisis de componentes principales (PCA) en R. Para ver si una especie se segrega en diferentes localidades a partir de las variables obtenida en cada localidad. Pero para poder ilustrar eso mejor tengo que agregar los poligonos de ordenacion pero el codigo que ofrece el paquete vegan no es muy explicativo.
Este s el codigo que uso:

```
data(dune)
mod <- rda(dune, scale = TRUE)
biplot(mod, scaling = "symmetric")

## different type for species and site scores
biplot(mod, scaling = "symmetric", type = c("text", "points"))
```

El grafico que obtengo es este:
[image: Imagen que obtengo]

Y esta es la imagen q la que se quiere llegar:
[image: Esto es lo que se desea. Tomado de https://www.benjaminbell.co.uk/2018/02/principal-components-analysis-pca-in-r.html]

COMO PUEDO PONER COLORES A LOS PUNTOS INTERIORES EN CORRESPONDENCIA A LAS ELIPSES
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres usar `Vegan`, para lo que buscas, tienes [`ordiellipse()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/ordihull), dónde claramente necesitaras una variable que determine el área. Tomando `iris` como ejemplo, emulamos tu área con la variable `Species`:

```
mod <-  rda(iris[,-5])

biplot(mod,
       display = c("sites", 
                   "species"),
       type = c("text",
                "points"),
       scaling = "symmetric")

ordiellipse(mod,  
            group = iris$Species, 
            kind = "ehull", 
            conf = 0.95,
            draw = "polygon",
            alpha = 20,
            col = c("red", "blue", "green"), 
            border = c("red", "blue", "green"), 
            lwd = 2)

legend("bottomright",
       col = c("red", "blue", "green"), 
       lty = 1,
       legend = levels(iris$Species))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude poner las elipses. una pregunta mas: como puedo poner el nombre a cada punto para saber q especie es la que esta en cada punto eso es importante.

Comment: El `data.frame` necesita `rownames` con la etiquetas a motrar, `biplot` usa esta información automáticamente, siempre que no sea un numero demasiado grande

Comment: Como puedo agregar numeros a la distribucion de puntos? Eso me permite saber si hay alguna especie q no se est'a segregando bien.